# Html5 Canvas working in WebView of Main Activity but stops working in WebView of Activity called using an intent in the same application

Tags: android, webview, html5-canvas

The device I'm testing on is running Android 2.3.4.

I have a Html5/JavaScript game.

Initially I had my menu and game in the same Activity and it worked fine. I just loaded the game URL from the Assets folder.

I wanted to changed it so that I launch the game in a new Activity:

```
    Intent gameIntent = new Intent(_context, GameActivity.class);

        gameIntent.putExtra("gameLocation", "file:///android_asset/game/index.html"); 

        ((Activity) _context).startActivity(gameIntent);
```

Then I load it in the new Activity:

```
gameWebView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("gameLocation"));
```

I use the very same settings for the WebView in both Activities with JavaScript enabled etc.

The standard HTML buttons and text render fine but the canvas element does not render although the correct amount of space is still taken up by the element.

I have no idea why it is not working. I even tried pointing the WebView to an online Html Canvas game and that doesn't work either. 
Edit: The game I pointed to does work in my standard phone browser and in the WebView of the Activity I have set as the launcher i.e.:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My main Activity where the game works has its launch mode set to single task. I have tried both standard and singleTop for the game Activity.

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

**EDIT:**
I have also tried setting the GameActivity to be the launcher and the Canvas element works. It appears that the problem only occurs when running the game in the Activity that has been launched as an Intent.

**Yet another EDIT** (this problem is really getting to me):

I think the problem stems from the fact both Activities are using WebViews. They point to completely different resources in my assets folder but Activity A(Main) is running JavaScript, then Activity B (GameActivity) is called with an intent and the Canvas doesn't render. If I replace Activity A with a plain Activity that has no WebView and just a button to launch Activity B, then the Canvas works in Activity B. In an attempt to fix that I call finish on Activity A as I start the intent for B but that still didn't work. Not sure what kind of an answer I'm expecting to this but maybe someone here knows the inner workings of all this and has a possible solution.

Comment: what is the value of `game.getLocation()`?

Comment: Hi, the location is file:///android_asset/game/index.html -             I have checked in debugging to ensure that hasn't gone wrong. Also the index.html is loading and most elements are rendering. It is just the Canvas element that is not working.

Comment: does your browser support the html5 canvas element?

Comment: It does. I am using the Android WebView which up to now has supported the Canvas element for me. It is only in this particular scenario that the element does not appear to be working. No errors appear to be thrown as far as I can tell from the logcat. I know I had a problem before with the cross domain thing, having JavaScript in different directories to the html but that doesn't appear to be the issue here as far as I can tell.

Comment: "I even tried pointing the WebView to an online Html Canvas game and that doesn't work either" - WebView aside, if you launch the same site from your browser does it work?

Comment: It does. I pointed to here http://playbiolab.com/ with the webview -and now my browser which I hadn't actually thought of until you suggested it. It works in my browser.

Comment: if you create a new project and strip everything away except a bare activity with a WebView, does the page display then?

Comment: It does. I did try that to see if I could figure anything out. I can go back to doing everything in one Activity and it will work. I would have liked to  use a second Activity for the game but for whatever reason it just doesn't seem to work. Even using the same project with the very same Activity set as the launcher, it works, but starting it with an intent causes the canvas not to work. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but a few things you should try

1. Try removing:

   android:launchMode="singleTask"
2. Make the WebView null before launching the new Activity
3. Try using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK so your Activity launches in a new task so the WebViews couldn't interfere

Comment: Hi Ferdau. Thanks for your suggestions. I tried them all. I really thought Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK would do it but amazingly even that didn't work. This is so weird. It couldn't be something in the code because the WebView Canvas in the very same Activity with no code changes works if the Activity is the Launcher or even called as an Intent from an Activity that does not have a WebView. Thanks for trying anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but it's one suggestion: Try calling `MySecondWebView.invalidate()` from within the second Activity - this will force the WebView to redraw itself.

Failing that, if separation of code/concerns/assets is all you're trying to achieve, why not just have the menu redirect the WebView to the game's html page?

```
document.location = "/game/index.html"
```

Oughta do it.

Comment: Hi aaronsnoswell. Thanks for your reply. I tried the invalidate method with no luck. I am currently using a similar method to what you mentioned for launching games. I was hoping to be able to launch a game in a new Activity because I wanted to have different settings on that Activity. It's not the end of the world. I can live without a second Activity but it is really tough to accept that this problem can't be fixed. Really appreciate your answer anyway though. I will try any suggestions. Never know what might work.